# WCF - OData: How to access an operation

Tags: c#, wcf, client, odata

I am using a child class of the `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext` gerated by the "adding a Service Reference" in VisualStudio to access data via an OData service. The definition in the `$metadata.xml` of the service includes a [custom operation](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/#operations):

```
<schema Namespace="dotNetBF.OData" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm">
    <EntityContainer Name="OData" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="SewageArea" EntityType="GeoMan.SealingRegister.SewageArea" />
        <EntitySet Name="LandParcel" EntityType="GeoMan.SealingRegister.LandParcel" />
        ...
        <AssociationSet Name="GeoMan_SealingRegister_SewageArea_LandParcel_GeoMan_SealingRegister_LandParcel_LandParcelPartnerSet" Association="GeoMan.SealingRegister.GeoMan_SealingRegister_SewageArea_LandParcel_GeoMan_SealingRegister_LandParcel_LandParcelPartner">
            <End Role="LandParcelPartner" EntitySet="SewageArea" />
            <End Role="LandParcel" EntitySet="LandParcel" />
        </AssociationSet>
        ...
        <FunctionImport Name="LandParcelByRegistrationYear" EntitySet="LandParcel" ReturnType="Collection(GeoMan.SealingRegister.LandParcel)">
            <Parameter Name="registrationYear" Mode="In" Type="Edm.String" />
        </FunctionImport>
    </EntityContainer>
</Schema>
```

How can I access the defined function `LandParcelByRegistrationYear` through the `DataServiceDeviceContext`, commit a value for parameter `registrationYear`and consume the result.

I already imported the `$metadata.xml` but cannot find a method given the name of the operation.